# How to change the colour of inactive bars in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to change the colours of the inactive bars in Highcharts I know how to change the opacity but there no option to set a different colour, here how my example looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events to update series colors:

```
var seriesColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

function applyColorState(e) {
    var allSeries = this.chart.series;

    allSeries.forEach(function(series, i) {
        if (series !== this) {
            series.update({
                color: e.type === 'mouseOver' ? 'gray' : seriesColors[i]
            }, false);
        }
    }, this);

    this.chart.redraw();
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            ...,
            events: {
                mouseOver: applyColorState,
                mouseOut: applyColorState
            }
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z42jn8dv/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.events

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

---

**EDIT:**

Add below plugin if you want to have the same functionality for legend:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'setItemEvents', function(proceed, points) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    this.allItems.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.legendGroup) {
        item.legendGroup.on('mouseover', function() {
          item.onMouseOver();
        });

        item.legendGroup.on('mouseout', function() {
          item.onMouseOut();
        });
      }
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z42jn8dv/1/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: thank you, this works now but the legend lost its functionality when hovering on any of the items it does not highlight the graph in the same way as hovering on parts of the graph itself

Comment: Hi @Kamel Labiad, You are right, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z42jn8dv/1/ it contains the additional functionality.

Comment: thank you very much it is working perfectly, could you update your answer so I chose it and an answer? thanks

Comment: @Kamel Labiad, Done.